# Firebase wants me to change my database url due to region

Tags: swift, database, firebase, url, firebase-realtime-database

The error message is as below:

*Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to *Same URL as my database indicates.**

While I'm trying to import some data on my Realtime DataBase of Firebase, This error keep showing. Which indicates that I need to change the URL of database because database is in another region.

The url that the app wants me to change is the same as the url of my database. So there seems to be no problem.

So do I need to change the url of database programmatically? If so how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to manually add the database URL in the ref.

> For a us-central1 default database, you can call database() (or database) without argument. To get a reference to a database other than a us-central1 default database, you must pass the database URL to database()

```
let ref = Database.database("https://<databaseName><region>.firebasedatabase.app")
```

You can read more about Relatime Database Locations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations).

[image]

The database URL of new database is shown while creating it as well (although the default URL is added in the Config).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue while learning Flutter and I wanted to add Firebase Realtime Database to the project.

**Note:** my solution may not work for everybody because I was just starting up the project.

Do the following:

1. Export your data (*if you don't want to lose it*)
2. Delete the project (as of the time of writing this, you cannot change the location of Firebase Realtime db once created.
3. Create another project
4. Create another Firebase Realtime db but **avoid changing the default location when creating a Firebase Realtime database**. The default location (for me) was **United States (us-central1)**
5. Import your exported data

Don't forget to add the new project settings to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same, in my case the terminal said I should change my database url to: "https://uberapp-b3347-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app".

Based on the google documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations)
the default database is in the US. Therefore i looked for the a file containing the .firebaseio.com

Specifically it was written as "https://%@-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com" in
FIRDDatabase.m file,

So i changed it to what the terminal said it should have which is "https://uberapp-b3347-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app"

It then worked successfully

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).